# How to use value in Python dataframe to determine what values will feature in matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to add in a hardcoded value on the y axis of my plot, dependent on what value exists in the dataframe. The code looks as per the below:

```
is_player = historics['Player Name'] == player_name
new_table = historics[is_player]
plt.bar(new_table.Date,new_table['Matchday Score'],color="g")
plt.title("%s's PB scores for 19/20 season" % player_name)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Matchday Score")
if new_table['FI Player Current Position'] == 'Forward':
    plt.axhline(y=255.56, color='gold', linestyle='-')
    plt.axhline(y=239.94, color='slategrey', linestyle='-')
    plt.axhline(y=173.52, color='saddlebrown', linestyle='-')
elif new_table['FI Player Current Position'] == 'Midfielder':
    plt.axhline(y=262.44, color='gold', linestyle='-')
    plt.axhline(y=263.35, color='slategrey', linestyle='-')
    plt.axhline(y=205.66, color='saddlebrown', linestyle='-')
else:
    plt.axhline(y=232.62, color='gold', linestyle='-')
    plt.axhline(y=227.43, color='slategrey', linestyle='-')
    plt.axhline(y=182.36, color='saddlebrown', linestyle='-')
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=20,10
plt.show()
```

However, when I run this, I get the below error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Anyone know how I overcome this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be quite simple. I simply replaced:

```
if new_table['FI Player Current Position'] == 'Forward':
```

with:

```
if 'Forward' in new_table['FI Player Current Position'].values:
```